# How can I get the max value and corresponding index of a tensor simultaneously in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

The only way I came out is using tf.argmax with tf.reduce_max. But I'm afraid of that it may be inefficient to find the max value twice.

Answer (score 1):

Before you worry about performance, I'd recommend profiling it. Finding the maximum is an inexpensive operation. Also, can you index into the element using the return value of argmax? That way you'd only take the max once.

Comment: Using the return value of argmax may be good for me. But how can I use the index to reduce specific dimension? For example, for a 4-dim tensor with shape (2,3,4,5), argmax(tensor,2) which return a tensor of shape (2,3,5), how can I use the index to get the max element of the tensor? Gather/gather_nd seems not available.

Comment: I've found a way. Using tf.one_hot first to extend the index tensor, tf.mul it with the original tensor, then tf.reduce_sum. Oh, maybe I'm ok to use tf.argmax and tf.reduce_max together :)

Comment: @HenrySky Thank you! Your solution with tf.one_hot was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: The one hot will work but will probably be inefficient.  The efficient solution probably involves using `tf.gather_nd(tensor, ixs)`, but exactly how to get these `ixs` from the output of `tf.argmax(tensor)` would take a little more thinking than I want to put into it now.

Answer (score 0):

As @chris suggested, it may actually be faster just to do `tf.reduce_max` and `tf.argmax` separately.

Here is some code that does it both ways.  By my measurements, doing it separately is nearly twice as fast (`0.36ms` vs `0.65ms` for a (20x30x40 array along axis 1), but that may be because my implementation of `tf_select_along_axis` is not as great as it could be.

Anyway, here's the code:

```
def tf_select_along_axis(arr, selecting_ixs, axis: int):
    """ Select the given indices along the given axis.
    :param arr: A N-dimensional tensor of shape (D[0], ..., D[axis], ..., D[N])
    :param selecting_ixs: A N-1 dimensional tensor of shape (D[0], ... D[axis-1], D[axis+1], ... D[N]) int32 which selects elements along axis
    :param axis: The axis along which you're selecting.
    """
    ixs = [tf.broadcast_to(tf.range(arr.shape[d])[(slice(None),) + (None,) * (axis - i)], selecting_ixs.shape) for i, d in enumerate(range(axis))] \
          + [selecting_ixs] \
          + [tf.broadcast_to(tf.range(arr.shape[d])[(slice(None),) + (None,) * (axis - i)], selecting_ixs.shape) for i, d in
             enumerate(range(axis + 1, len(arr.shape)), start=axis + 1)]
    ixs_nd = tf.reshape(tf.stack(ixs, axis=-1), (-1, len(arr.shape)))
    return tf.reshape(tf.gather_nd(arr, ixs_nd), selecting_ixs.shape)


def tf_argmax_and_max(arr, axis: int, separate_implementation=True) -> Tuple[tf.Tensor, tf.Tensor]:
    """ Get both the argmax and max """
    if separate_implementation:
        return tf.argmax(arr, axis=axis, output_type=tf.int32), tf.reduce_max(arr, axis=axis)  # For now...
    else:
        argmax = tf.argmax(arr, axis=axis, output_type=tf.int32)
        return argmax, tf_select_along_axis(arr, argmax, axis=axis)
```

And here's the test used to demo it:

````
def test_argmax_and_max_and_select_along_axis():
    arr = tf.random.uniform((20, 30, 40), seed=1234)
    for _ in range(5):
        for seperate in (False, True):
            with easy_profile('Seperate' if seperate else 'Max from Argmax'):
                argmax, max = tf_argmax_and_max(arr, axis=1, separate_implementation=seperate)
                max_again = tf_select_along_axis(arr, selecting_ixs=argmax, axis=1)
                assert tf.reduce_all(max == max_again).numpy()

```
````